# Qt: spliter in QListView

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlistview

I've got `QListView` that shows list of files, which is selected by mask from the folder by `QFileSystemModel`. I'm trying to change the distance `QListView::setSpacing(int space)`, but i've got spacing after and before record list changed instead. Looks like `QListView` has uploaded a list as a single object.

How should I fix it?

Comment: screenshots describing what you want to do could also be helpful

Comment: Look - https://s17.postimg.org/cs341r3u7/bug.png other - https://s16.postimg.org/pv1vju0h1/no_bug.png